# Expression conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

I am still a little green to Expressions and having difficulty figuring this problem out.  This may be more of a Lambda expression issue over EF, but I am hoping someone can atleast point me in the correct direction:

I am attempting to do the following:

```
internal static IQueryable<TSource> WithSecurity<TSource>(thisIQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<Security.Access, TSource, bool>> predicate, params MyRoles[] roles)
{

    DL.MyContext ctx = Csla.Data.DbContextManager<DL.MyContext>.GetManager().DbContext;

    var accessData = ctx.Access.Where(e => roles.Contains((MyRoles)e.Role_ID));

    Expression x = predicate asLambdaExpression;

    source =
        from c in source
        where accessData.Any(predicate)
        select c;

    return source;
}
```

On the where clause, there is clearly a problem as the predicate is of type `Expression<Func<Security.Access, TSource, bool>>`, but the Any is expecting `Expression<Func<Security.Access, bool>>`.  Any assistance on how to convert will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you want something like `where accessData.Any(ad => predicate(c, ad))`?

Comment: Yes!  But it's giving me an error.  "'predicate' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'"

Comment: Then have a look at [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), I think that's exactly what you need.

Comment: This feels like it's more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Why don't you enter an `Expression<Func<Security.Access, bool>>` as parameter?

Comment: Just tried.  It gave me nested expressions.  Do you have a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the Compile method:

```
var compiledPredicate = predicate.Compile();
source = 
    from c in source 
    where accessData.Any(ad => compiledPredicate(ad, c)) 
    select c;
```

Note that Compile is a somewhat expensive operation so if this methods gets invoked frequently with the same expression in a typical scenario consider caching the result from Compile().

Comment: This looks good and makes sense.  I am getting the following error though:  **The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Int32'
Parameter name: value**

Comment: I got it working!  I changed the source = to **source.Where(s => accessData.Any(ad => compiledPredicate(ad, s)));** This worked.